# Redis Lua eval and pubsub - send a command on a message?

Tags: lua, redis, eval

Is it possible to use lua evaluation to hang out and listen to a pubsub channel, replying with a command on a certain message?

Edit: Seems pubsub has been implemented. I'm a little unclear on how to approach this (lua green).
https://github.com/nrk/redis-lua/issues/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `subscribe` is not allowed in scripts. Scripts are executed in the same event loop as everything else in redis, meaning, while your script is executing no other commands get executed.

Further, the library you are linking to is a lua client library. [Here](http://redis.io/commands/eval) is the relevant documentation for lua scripting in redis.

Comment: Ya thanks - I don't know why I didn't see that I was looking at a lua client!! I just implemented it in a client I was using instead.